# Swatcher PNG trancparency doesn't work and makes background black (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, swatches, small-image

Transparent part of my PNG Files get black on color swatcher images. In product photos it seems to work fine. Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Have you got your solution?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new module and place a 'etc' and 'Helper' directory inside:

App > Code > Vendor > SwatchTransparency > etc > di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media" type="Vendor\SwatchTransparency\Helper\Media" />
</config>
```

App > Code > Vendor > SwatchTransparency > etc > module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_SwatchTransparency" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

App > Code > Vendor > SwatchTransparency > Helper > Media.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\SwatchTransparency\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;

class Media extends \Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media
{
    protected function setupImageProperties(\Magento\Framework\Image $image, $isSwatch = false)
    {
        $image->quality(100);
        $image->constrainOnly(true);
        $image->keepAspectRatio(true);
        $image->keepTransparency(true);
        if ($isSwatch) {
            $image->keepFrame(true);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

App > Code > Vendor > SwatchTransparency > registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_SwatchTransparency',
    __DIR__
);
```

Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Run `php bin/magento cache:clean`